# Removing from Tail on LinkedList in Elm (vs JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, data-structures, elm

I recognize that this probably isn't an exact implementation of a Linked List in JavaScript but here's what I have:

```
// a Node is either null or { value: value, next: Node }
function createNode(value) {
    return { value: value, next: null };
}

function isEmpty(node) {
    return node === null;
}

function addToHead(value, node) {
    var newNode = createNode(value);
    newNode.next = node;
    return newNode;
}

function addToTail(value, node) {
    var newNode = createNode(value);
    if (isEmpty(node)) return newNode;
    node.next = addToTail(value, node.next);
    return node;
}

function contains(value, node) {
    if (isEmpty(node)) return false;
    if (node.value === value) return true;
    return contains(value, node.next);
}

function removeFromTail(node) {
    if (isEmpty(node) || isEmpty(node.next)) return null;
    var current = node;
    var next = current.next;
    while (next.next) {
        current = next;
        next = next.next;
    }
    current.next = null;
    return node;
}
```

**The question I have is how would you implement the removeFromTail code in Elm - especially my code involves mutation and re-binding references.**

Here's a partial re-implementation in Elm:

```
type List a = Empty | Node a (List a)

addToHead value list =
  case list of
    Empty ->
      Node value Empty
    Node _ _ ->
      Node value list

contains value list =
  case list of
    Empty ->
      False
    Node v sublist ->
      if v == value then
        True
      else
        contains value sublist
```

**However, I'm stuck on addToTail and removeFromTail because I'm not sure how I could do this without potentially re-building a new list.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manipulation at the tail of an immutable linked list means that the list will need to be reconstructed. There's no way around that.

Since `List a` is a built-in Elm type, I'd also recommend changing the name to avoid name collisions.

```elm
type MyList a = Empty | Node a (MyList a)
```

`addToTail` is then a matter of consing the items given a new last item:

```elm
addToTail : a -> MyList a -> MyList a
addToTail val list =
  case list of
    Empty -> Node val Empty
    Node x xs -> Node x <| addToTail val xs
```

And removing that last item can be done by returning a tuple containing the last item and the new list. That new list can be built by mapping over the Maybe value (the Maybe being introduced because you can't get the last item of an empty list):

```elm
removeFromTail : MyList a -> Maybe (a, MyList a)
removeFromTail list =
  case list of
    Empty -> Nothing
    Node x Empty -> Just (x, Empty)
    Node x xs -> Maybe.map (\(y, ys) -> (y, Node x ys)) <| removeFromTail xs
```

Comment: this is super helpful! Out of curiosity, is there some literature behind why tail manipulation of immutable listed list must involve rebuilding it? Trying to learn more!

Comment: The key word is "manipulation". Manipulating a value is impossible, so you have to create a new value that points at the rest of the list (in the last item's case, it points at `Empty`). Now that you have a new value, all values pointing at the new value have to be updated to point at that new value, but again, you can't manipulate something immutable, so every value pointing at the new value has to be recreated, all the way up the list.